# $k[\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{a,b\}] \cong \{\frac{p(x)}{(x-a)^{m_1}(x-b)^{m_2}}\}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{a,b\}$ is isomorphic as a quasi-affine variety to the affine variety $\{(x,t) \in \mathbb{A}^2 : t(x-a)(x-b)=1\}$, by the maps $x \mapsto (x,\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)})$ and $(x,t) \mapsto x$. Thus they have the same coordinate ring, $\frac{k[x]}{(t(x-a)(x-b)-1)}$, which is isomorphic to the localization of $k[x]$ at $((x-a)(x-b)-1)$. These are the functions of the form $\frac{p(x)}{((x-a)(x-b))^m}$.

However, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGDG75_2B2g&list=PLCgncMh0TrCkiiuBH1fcioW8uFO9S_KPE&index=12) claims that the coordinate ring is actually isomorphic to the ring of functions of the form $\frac{p(x)}{(x-a)^{m_1}(x-b)^{m_2}}$. Why is that so? And are those two rings really isomorphic? They don't seem like they are.

Comment: You can always add some factors of $x-a$ or $x-b$ to $p(x)$ to get things to work out.

Comment: $k[x,t]_{\displaystyle/(t(x-a)(x-b)-1)}$ is the localization of $k[x]$ at the ideal $((x-a)(x-b))$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered in a comment by @Hoot (Thanks!):

"One can always add some factors of $x−a$ or $x−b$ to $p(x)$ to get things to work out." So the two rings are indeed isomorphic.